# How to print a struct using a file in C

Tags: c, struct, file-manipulation

The data file has weather data for Miami and Toronto (city name, the date, temperature, precipitation). I need to create a function that prints a struct but the values are in a .txt file. This is the file: (info.txt)

```
Miami,2,-6.4,0
Toronto,2,9.5,0.8
Miami,3,-11.7,0
Toronto,3,6.1,0
```

This is the struct:

```
struct Weather{

    char location;  //will be "M" or "T"
    int daynum;
    double temp;
    double precip;
};
```

This is a parser function:

```
void parseLine(char toParse[], struct Weather * toLoad)
{     
    char * theToken;     
    theToken = strtok(toParse, ",");     
    toLoad->location = theToken[0];     
    theToken = strtok(NULL, ",");     
    toLoad->daynum = atoi(theToken);     
    theToken = strtok(NULL, ",");     
    if(theToken != NULL)
    {         
        toLoad->temp = atof(theToken);     
    }     
    else     
    {         
        toLoad->temp = -400;     
    }     
    theToken = strtok(NULL, ",");     
    if(theToken != NULL)     
    {         
        toLoad->precip = atof(theToken);     
    }     
    else     
    {         
        toLoad->precip = -1.0; 
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I use the struct and the parse function to create another function that prints the values of location, daynum, temp, and precip.

Note: im using argc and argv in my main function. You should also know im new to file manipulation and so I'm not exactly sure how to use file functions correctly.

Edit: My primary problem is figuring out what to do in 'main' so that I can create the print function

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Why can't you just use printf? It seems like you got the "harder" parts done.

Comment: What is wrong with using something like printf("%s,%d,%lf,%lf", st->location == 'M' ? "Miami" : "Toronto", st->daynum, st->temp, st->precip); ?

Comment: but don't i have to open the file and do things with the file thats the main problem (in 'main' im not sure what to do)

Comment: @JohnSmith Is your intent perhaps to modify the input file? Do you want to read the file, modify it's data, then write it back? In that case you might want to let your `parseLine` function take a `FILE *`, and pass it `stdin`. This way you could run the program like: `myProg.exe < info.txt > info.txt`.

Comment: no i do not want to modify its data. I will get back to you if your answer works

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```c
void printStruct(FILE *fout, struct Weather *in)
{
    fprintf(fout, "%s,%d,%f,%f", in->location == 'M' ? "Miami" : "Toronto", in->daynum, in->temp, in->precip);
}
```

Use it as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ELEMSIZE(arr) (sizeof(*arr))
#define ARRAYSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr)/ELEMSIZE(arr))

int main(void)
{
    char line[1024];
    struct Weather weather;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("info.txt", "r");
    fread(line, ELEMSIZE(line), ARRAYSIZE(line), fp);
    parseLine(line, &weather);
    printStruct(stdout, &weather);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: You might want to change the first argument to `parseLine` to be a `FILE *` (You will have to do some magic to get `strtok` to work, but it will improve efficiency as well as flexability and scalability).

Comment: so im getting a ton of errors/warnings when i try to run it

Comment: ahhh you didn't use argc/argv

Comment: @JohnSmith It _should_ compile, but I did not check... Update: All warnings I get are from the coded copied from your question.